# Trouble using ssh in a Mac Automator Service

Tags: ssh, applescript, automator

I am trying to create an Automator Service that runs an applescript that eventually runs a bash script to ssh/scp to a server:

--

I have this applescript that saves my current photoshop document and calls a bash script to scp the image to a server.  The bash script then runs ssh to do some stuff on said server with the image.

I have an ssh-askpass file and it seems to work well in most situations.  I even tried reinstalling it to make sure I didn't goof on permissions, but it seems to be in good shape.

If I just run the applescript through Applescript Editor, it works fine and goes through ssh-askpass.

I want to create an Automator action (using the "service" template) to run my applescript, so I can just make it into a keyboard shortcut.

If I just run the script in Automator, everything works fine.  Unfortunately, when I try to use the service outside automator (ie App Menu > Services), it seems that my Automator action is not attempting to go through ssh-askpass at all (which I verified with temporary logging)- everything works fine up to that point.

I looked into it a bit more, and it appears that a similar issue occurs when I try to run the applescript from the terminal (and not Applescript Editor)

--

Is there something different I need to do to ensure that an applescript (in Automator) uses ssh-askpass?

Comment: How are you invoking ssh-askpass?

Comment: Why don't you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.  In the bash script I was calling, I was exporting the SSH_ASKPASS path, but not the display:

export DISPLAY=":0"

Apparently the AppleScript Editor (and XCode and Automator) does the exports for you, which is why it was working in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over your account on the server (e.g. shell account), I would just generate an SSH keypair and use it for authentication. That way, you can truly automate the exchange and not have to deal with `ssh-askpass` at all.

See http://paulkeck.com/ssh/ for a guide to making and deploying SSH keys.

Comment: I unfortunately do not.  Also my server does not support ssh keys, that was actually the first thing I tried.